# Writing name of file with data in a single frame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is length (141,2) with a repetition of Year and Month that I have stripped from files in a folder that just looks like:

```
Year          Month
2017            1
2017            1
2017            1
2017            1
2017            1
2017            1
2017            1
.
.
```

Each file that I stripped from has around (20000, 6) rows and I want to repeat the Year and Month on each of the files.

I take a list in for the files from the directory to strip the year and months like:

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'C:\\.....')
files = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i))]
```

And then from the list `files` I just iterate through each file like:

```
for file in files:
    df['Year'] = os.path.split(file)[1]
    df['Year'] = df['Year'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-6])
```

How can I just write the entire file to a dataframe and join these dates I've stripped in repetition to the entire length of the file?

Ie: Make the (141,2) dataframe just append and become a (20000,2) frame?

Comment: The list `files` correctly lists all your target files and nothing else, right? Did you confirm that?

Comment: Yes they do. All files concat into the list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`Dask` can easily construct a dataframe from a glob of files with a path wildcard e.g. `"./*.csv"`, but that might be overkill for your problem.

Another way is to use `concat`.

`df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, ...) for f in files, ignore_index=True])`

Edit:

Unspooling this to do your `map` would basically look like:

```
df = []
for file in files:
    tdf = pd.DataFrame()
    tdf['Year'] = os.path.split(file)[1]
    df.append(tdf['Year'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-6]))
 df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: In your second example, you should still append to a **list** within the loop and then concatenate afterwards. Appending to a `DataFrame` within a loop unnecessarily copies the data every iteration.